# Can I set my modulepath in my site.pp somehow?

Tags: puppet

I don't have a puppet master.  And I'm too lazy to type the --modulepath option on the commandline.  Can I set my modulepath in my site.pp somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could set it in `[main]` or `[user]` (when using `puppet apply`) in `puppet.conf`.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of.  I don't really want to bother with messing around with my puppet.conf either.  I guess I will just have to use --modulepath.  Thanks!